# Problem with intents :MacroDroid

Tags: automation, intents, macrodroid

I am not able to get the intent running for this [out loud app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hillman.out_loud). App description says

> - Launch these *activities* to change the on/off state of Out Loud:
>   `com.hillman.out_loud.activity.OnActivity`

> - To change the on/off state through a *broadcast* intent, send a broadcast with these details:

> `Action: com.hillman.out_loud.ON_OFF`
> `Data: out_loud://on_off?state=[state]`

whether I use activity or broadcast.

**What am I doing wrong?**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *turn on* the Out Loud using automation app, do this:

- Target: Activity
- Package: `com.hillman.out_loud`
- Class: `com.hillman.out_loud.activity.OnActivity`

Leave the rest entries untouched.

If you want to *turn off* the Out Loud, do this:

- Target: Activity
- Package: `com.hillman.out_loud`
- Class: `com.hillman.out_loud.activity.OffActivity`

If you want to toggle the state, do this:

- Target: Activity
- Package: `com.hillman.out_loud`
- Class: `com.hillman.out_loud.activity.ToggleOnOffActivity`

Check your notification panel/bar to see the changes. If toggled to On state, Loud Out would create a notification (low priority), else the notification would be missing.

Comment: Also, why is the *action* blank? Guess I am mixing up things here

Comment: I am not good with Android's internals, so I don't know why Action has to be left blank. But I usually keep it blank anyway. As for class -- it is the activity name that you have to supply there. Data is not expected by those activities unless you are broadcasting and since data is not expected, mime type (the data type you are sending) is also not expected so both needs to be blank if you are choosing Activity as Target.