# Help with intents: MacroDroid

Tags: intents, macrodroid

Further to this [Problem with intents :MacroDroid](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226362/131553), the solution in the accepted answer works but sadly only for the first time (app error) . I have [reported this to the developer](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/macrodroid/viewtopic.php?p=33472#p33472)

Meanwhile, I thought of trying to see if a *broadcast* intent would solve the problem. Lacking understanding of how intents work, I tried this and other combinations (`ON` in square bracket, Action same as class) , but couldn't get it to work.

[image]

Here is the Tasker intent that works

[image]

Request help in constructing broadcast intent.

NOTE:Please don't edit to make the images smaller for the sake of readability, let them be

Comment: The URI you use in class is (as far as I can read this tiny screenshot) wrong. The hostname needs to be `on_off` but using online URI parser your URI does not have a host because of the missing `/`. Therefore I would try `out_loud://on_off/?state=[state]` However it still may not work because the app author have chosen an invalid scheme. `out_loud://` is not a valid URI according to the [RFC3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.1): underscores are not allowed.

Comment: What do you mean by only for the first time?

Comment: @Firelord No fault of yours :), though it sounded like that and now edited. As you can see in the linked bug report, it worked fine till I updated MacroDroid. After that, whenever I create a macro, it runs for the first time and thereafter doesn't. FairEmail is sending intents fine, this bug is getting my goat :(. I did all the usual stuff, clear cache, reboot, permissions, battery optimization exclude. Just now, added Tasker intent (ya, figured out how to do this) - hope that points to a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works. No idea for the logic behind it. Any body knows why, please edit to explain or answer

[image]

Comment: The "Action" needs to be filled according to [the same action, set as the intent filters for the broadcast receiver in the manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#manifest-declared-receivers), as shown on [the example of sending broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#sending-broadcasts)

Comment: @AndrewT Thanks for the clarification. I will bear this in mind next time I try. This particular attempt is abandoned because it's not needed and FairEmail has added this feature (of reading aloud mails based on sender rule)