# Find `MainActivity` for `com.google.android.dialer`

Tags: adb, shell, tasker, command-line, termux

I have a Xiaomi POCO X5 5G, running MIUI Global 14.0.4.

There is a problem where (in the Global ROM) the Google Phone app (as a system app) seems to be killed, even with MIUI Battery Optimization disabled. There is no option for Autostart in settings.

If someone knows how to force enable Autostart for a system app (when the option is not present) please let me know, but for now, let's look at the Y of this X/Y problem.

I am trying to resolve this issue using Tasker. I have a profile that triggers on Display Off event. The task it should run is to start the phone app in the background. I have found the following command, which I've put in Run Shell:

- `am startservice -n com.google.android.dialer/.MainActivity`
- `am startservice -n com.google.android.dialer/.main.impl.MainActivity`
- `am startservice -n com.android.dialer/.MainActivity`
- `am startservice -n com.android.dialer/.main.impl.MainActivity`
- `am startservice -n com.android.dialer.Dialer_Application/.MainActivity`

And many, many other attempts. I am running these commands in Termux as root to try to find one that works. I am looking at `AndroidManifest.xml` to see what all the possible activities are. I can't figure it out, I always see:

```
Starting service: Intent { cmp=com.google.android/.MainActivity }
Error: Not found: no services started.
```

I have even used an app to create a shortcut to start that activity, and then copied the settings from that app. Nothing seems to work.

How can I start the dialer in the background using Tasker?

Comment: See Andrew's comments 
 https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226427/help-with-intents-macrodroid/226430#comment303719_226430

Comment: The commands seem about trying to start a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) instead of an [`Activity`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities)?

Comment: @AndrewT. I want to start whatever services or activities are necessary for the phone to receive calls while the screen is locked. I don't know much about Android development.